# Overlay inside scrollable div not showing correctly

Tags: html, css

I've a scrollable div. Inside this div I've a absolut positioned overlay. Sadly, this overlay is stuck at the top. So when I scroll down, the overlay stays at the top:

```css
.list {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid;
}

span {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  height: 33px;
  background: red;
}

span:nth-child(2n) {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1000;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

The overlay get's visible when the user presses a button. When he don't scroll down, everything looks good but when he does, don't. So any idea how to expand the overlay over the whole scrollable div elements?

Comment: My solution is different then the duplicate. Sadly I can't share it with you becasue Temani Afif marked my question as a duplicate. But I'm scrolling now hard to the top in the scrollable div to get the overlay back into the view.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant but you could use `position:sticky`

```css
.list {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid;
}

span {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  height: 33px;
  background: red;
}

span:nth-child(2n) {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1000;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: default;
  position: sticky;
}

.content {
  margin-top: -100%
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position: fixed;` is relative to the viewport (browser window) rather than to an element. If he would use it, the whole screen would be overlaid...

Comment: Missed that part - answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe a solution would be to scroll at the top inside the div on button click so the overlay will be in the viewport?